# jquery to create sliding page in one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this website combines many page in one page with sliding, does any body know which javascript or jquery library used for this site ?

http://www.ariansina.com/

Also if you have jquery code for this, I hope you post it as answer

thanks

Comment: There's a list of all scripts at the very bottom of the page source.

Comment: `View source` option in you browser.

Comment: Look at the page source code they are using `jQuery` `modernizir` `Pxloader` and other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll get the complete jQuery code for another guys hard work on stackoverflow.

But to get you started, here are a few jQuery libraries, that can accomplish this:

[fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage)
[jQuery OnePage Scroll](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html)
[onePage scroll with animations](https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/one-page-scroll-animations/)

I think this one comes closest to what you need:
[revealJS](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/2/1)

And my favourite (I know, I shouldn't play favourites but it's just too impressive to ignore): [impress.js](http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/#/bored)